# How can I convert a universal date time string to a DateTime instance?

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert the string below to a DateTime instance in C#?

> Wed Sep 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)

Comment: And you tried what? What failed?

Comment: Just look at all the `Related` posts that pop up on the right side... feels like similar questions get asked here at least twice a day.

Comment: A quick google threw up this which looks like a good starting point if you ahven't tried it already:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165448.aspx

Comment: At least make an attempt at a solution, you might learn something

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert weird date format to short DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330219/convert-weird-date-format-to-short-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
string date = "Wed Sep 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530";
var datex = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT+0530", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```